# getting null json grid data from jqgrid in struts2 action class .please guide in proper direction

Tags: jqgrid, struts2

$.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "SendData.action",
                                dataType:"JSON",
                                data : dataToSend,
                                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                success: function(response, textStatus, xhr) {
                                    alert("success");
                                },
                                error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                    alert("error");
                                }

```
                        });
```

dataToSend getter and setter..
should i have to parse into java array list or simply i have to print dataToSend

Comment: can anyone guide me in proper direction

Answer (score 0):

in ajax send data as below

```
 data :{"dataToSend":data} //where "data" is the data which u want to send
```

and datatype of "dataToSend" depends on the type of the data u send.